# How to justify text in center in gtk label in C

Tags: gtk, label

I have a `Gtk Label` and I want to show a single line text onto it. For example the text is:

```
Linux is a Unix-like computer operating system
```

Now I want to display this text in the centre of the label. But the problem is it only appears on the top.

Here is the code I am using for it:

```
Message_Label = gtk_label_new (" ");
gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), Message_Label, 0, 1, 2, 1);

gtk_label_set_line_wrap_mode(GTK_LABEL(Message_Label),PANGO_WRAP_WORD);
gtk_label_set_line_wrap(GTK_LABEL(Message_Label),TRUE);
gtk_misc_set_alignment (GTK_MISC (Message_Label), 0.5, 0.5);
gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(Message_Label),GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
```

and this is how it looks like:

[image]

Can anyone give me any ideas on what is wrong here.

Comment: Why do you use a grid if there is no content on it other than your label? How is the container hierarchy? The parent of the grid is a window?

Comment: @JoséFonte I have three labels. Two of them are aligned on top left and top right. This one (message_label) is below it. So I used a grid

Comment: @S Andrew Ok, Tnx for feedback. I would suggest, as @AndreLDM said, you to use Glade and play with all the available parameters. You'll understand how layout works in Gtk and  then implement it programmatically or use GtkBuilder. GL

Comment: @JoséFonte Yes I know  about glade and in the starting I used it for UI. But in my application I need to display the application in full screen mode and I was not able to do it while using glade. So I had to move back to using the gtk to make UI.

Comment: @S Andrew You can do it in Glade too, just retrieve the window and then change parameters programmatically. Anyway, the tip is for you to experiment with layout. If you also install devhelp package, then you can check which UI parameter corresponds on the API/Reference.

Comment: @JoséFonte sure I will definetly try some time.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should the vexpand property to make the label fill the free vertical space. See the working sample:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window, *grid, *label;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "App Sample");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 600, 400);

    grid = gtk_grid_new ();
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), grid);

    label = gtk_label_new ("Linux is a Unix-like computer operating system ");
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), label, 0, 0, 1, 1);

    gtk_widget_set_vexpand (label, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_hexpand (label, TRUE);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Sample screenshot]

But as [José Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7728864/jos%c3%a9-fonte) asked, why are you using a Grid when you only have a label? Probably to make the question simpler, but out of its original context, the grid seems bloat.

I'd recommend [Glade](https://glade.gnome.org/) to create the UI, your code will be cleaner and you'll easily put your UI together without fighting the API and wasting hours in a try-compile-assert-repeat cycle. [GtkInspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/Inspector) is also of great help.